# Unable to fix libwine-development dependencies on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 18.04, apt, upgrade, 20.04, dependencies

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 (from Ubuntu 18.04). During the upgrade, I noticed some dependencies issues related to `libwine-developement` package. After upgrade, I tried to `update` and `upgrade` the packages to see if dependencies get fixed.

```
sudo apt upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwine-development : Breaks: libwine-development:i386 (!= 5.5-3ubuntu1) but 3.6-1 is installed
 libwine-development:i386 : Breaks: libwine-development (!= 3.6-1) but 5.5-3ubuntu1 is installed
 wine32-development:i386 : Depends: libwine-development:i386 (= 5.5-3ubuntu1) but 3.6-1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Also, tried to fix things by:

```
sudo apt autoremove

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwine-development : Breaks: libwine-development:i386 (!= 5.5-3ubuntu1) but 3.6-1 is installed
 libwine-development:i386 : Breaks: libwine-development (!= 3.6-1) but 5.5-3ubuntu1 is installed
 wine32-development:i386 : Depends: libwine-development:i386 (= 5.5-3ubuntu1) but 3.6-1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

#sudo apt --fix-broken install

....
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libwine-development_5.5-3
ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/wine-development/arp.exe.dpkg-new': No 
such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the loc
al system
         Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libwine-development_5.5-3ubuntu1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

#sudo dpkg --configure -a

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine32-development:i386:
 wine32-development:i386 depends on libwine-development (= 5.5-3ubuntu1); however:
  Version of libwine-development:i386 on system is 3.6-1.

dpkg: error processing package wine32-development:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: error processing package libwine-development:amd64 (--configure):
 package libwine-development:amd64 5.5-3ubuntu1 cannot be configured because libwine-development:i386 is at a different version (3.6-1)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine64-development:
 wine64-development depends on libwine-development (= 5.5-3ubuntu1); however:
  Package libwine-development:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package wine64-development (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine-development:
 wine-development depends on wine64-development (>= 5.5-3ubuntu1) | wine32-development (>= 5.5-3ubuntu1); however:
  Package wine64-development is not configured yet.
  Package wine32-development:i386 is not configured yet.
 wine-development depends on wine64-development (<< 5.5-3ubuntu1.1~) | wine32-development (<< 5.5-3ubuntu1.1~); however:
  Package wine64-development is not configured yet.
  Package wine32-development:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package wine-development (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wine32-development:i386
 libwine-development:amd64
 wine64-development
 wine-development
```

The dependency problem seems to persist. I would like to fix the dependency issue by getting rid of broken packages and getting a stable wine package. Can someone help me to fix the issue?

**Update 1:**

I tried funicorn's suggestion, and here is the output so far.

```
#aptitude why-not libwine-development
Automatically installed, current version 5.5-3ubuntu1, priority optional
No dependencies require to remove libwine-development
```

and, this command tried to solve dependencies but ended up in an error:

```
#sudo aptitude install -f --safe-resolver
Resolving dependencies...                
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gconf2-common python-matplotlib-data 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gcc-8-base:i386{u} libffi6:i386{u} libhogweed4:i386{u} libicu60:i386{u} libncurses5:i386{u} libnettle6:i386{u} libsane1:i386{u} 
  libsndio6.1:i386{u} libspeexdsp1:i386{u} libtinfo5:i386{u} 
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libwine-development:i386 
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  libc-bin libwine-development wine-development wine32-development:i386 wine64-development
...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libwine-development_5.5-3ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/wine-development/arp.exe.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
                                                                                         Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libwine-development_5.5-3ubuntu1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Update 2:**

```
#dpkg -s libwine-development:i386

Package: libwine-development
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 181661
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: i386
Multi-Arch: same
Source: wine-development
Version: 3.6-1
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27), libfontconfig1 (>= 2.12), libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1), libncurses5 (>= 6), libtinfo5 (>= 6), libasound2 (>= 1.0.16), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0), libgphoto2-6 (>= 2.5.10), libgphoto2-port12 (>= 2.5.10), libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 (>= 1.0.0), libgstreamer1.0-0 (>= 1.4.0), liblcms2-2 (>= 2.2+git20110628), libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7), libmpg123-0 (>= 1.13.7), libopenal1 (>= 1.14), libpcap0.8 (>= 0.9.8), libpulse0 (>= 0.99.1), libudev1 (>= 183), libx11-6, libxext6, libxml2 (>= 2.9.0), ocl-icd-libopencl1 | libopencl1, ocl-icd-libopencl1 (>= 1.0) | libopencl-1.1-1, zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
Recommends: libcapi20-3, libcups2 (>= 1.4.0), libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14), libgl1, libglu1-mesa | libglu1, libgnutls30 (>= 3.5.0), libgsm1 (>= 1.0.13), libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2), libjpeg8 (>= 8c), libkrb5-3 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2), libodbc1 (>= 2.3.1), libosmesa6 (>= 10.2~), libpng16-16 (>= 1.6.2-1), libsane1 (>= 1.0.24), libtiff5 (>= 4.0.3), libv4l-0 (>= 0.5.0), libxcomposite1 (>= 1:0.3-1), libxcursor1 (>> 1.1.2), libxfixes3, libxi6, libxinerama1, libxrandr2, libxrender1, libxslt1.1 (>= 1.1.25), libxxf86vm1, libgl1-mesa-dri, libasound2-plugins, fonts-liberation, fonts-wine (>= 1.8.2-1~)
Suggests: cups-bsd, ttf-mscorefonts-installer
Description: Windows API implementation - library
 Wine is a free MS-Windows API implementation.
 This is still a work in progress and many applications may still not work.
 .
 This package provides the Wine library.
Original-Maintainer: Debian Wine Party <wine@tracker.debian.org>
Built-Using: khronos-api (= 0~svn33340-0.1), unicode-data (= 10.0.0-3)
Homepage: https://www.winehq.org
```

Comment: Would you add to the question the output of: `apt-cache policy libwine-development libwine-development:i386`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you turn to `aptitude` for some explanations / suggestions. e.g.

```
# aptitude why-not libwine-development
# aptitude install -f --safe-resolver
# aptitude install -f
```

Of course you can try removing the unwanted package

```
# aptitude remove -f libwine-development
```

Before you make certain choice to proceed, think it over.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I updated my question I ran into another error after `# aptitude install -f --safe-resolver`.

Comment: I am not even able to remove the package `# aptitude remove -f libwine-development`. This command also ended up in the same `dpkg` error in my update 1.

Comment: khajlk, you should first let dpkg complete configuration of libc-bin. Then, can you confirm the package status via `dpkg -s libwine-development:i386`?

Comment: funicorn, Not sure what you meant by letting dpkg complete libc-bin configuration. I can't update, upgrade, install and remove packages at the moment. I have updated my question for status via `dpkg -s libwine-development:i386`.